# Issue with multiple filter using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html-page with multiple filter using `Vanilla JavaScript` (no jQuery). Filtering is done by counting matches of filter selections against matches of the same for each of the element data attributes.

I don't understand why the filter doesn't work with all data attributes (key) .
I tried to explain my problem with code snippet. The filter only works for no more than two of my data attributes (in the example - subject and form).

```js
(function() {

  var el = {};

  function matches(key, value) {
    var count = 0;
    Array.from(el.items).forEach(item => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'category':
          if (item.dataset.category.includes(value)) {
            count++;
          }
          break;
        case 'subject':
          if (item.dataset.subject.includes(value)) {
            count++;
          }
          break;
        case 'schoolclass':
           if (item.dataset.schoolclass.includes(value)) {
            count ++;
          }
          break;
         case 'form':
          if (item.dataset.form.includes(value)) {
            count ++;
          }
          break;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }

  function match(item) {
    var match = {
      "category": [],
      "subject": [],
      "schoolclass": [],
      "form": []
    };
    Array.from(el.filtersList).forEach(input => {
      if (input.checked) {
        switch (input.name) {
          case 'category':         
          match.category.push(item.dataset.category.includes(input.value));
            break;
          case 'subject':         
          match.subject.push(item.dataset.subject.includes(input.value));
            break;
          case 'schoolclass':     
          match.schoolclass.push(item.dataset.schoolclass.includes(input.value));
           break;
          case 'form':         
          match.form.push(item.dataset.form.includes(input.value));
            break;
        }
      }
    });
    return match;
  }

  function renderCount(count) {
    el.heading.innerHTML = `finded: ${count} resources`;
  }

  function applyFilter() {
    Array.from(el.items).forEach(item => {
      var result = match(item),
        matches = [];
      item.classList.remove('selected');

      // console.log(result);
      if (result.category.length) {
        if (result.category.includes(true)) {
          matches.push(true);
        } else {
          matches.push(false);
        }
      }

      if (result.subject.length) {
        if (result.subject.includes(true)) {
          matches.push(true);
        } else {
          matches.push(false);
        }
      }
      
      if (result.form.length) {
                if (result.form.includes(true)) {
                    matches.push(true);
                } else { matches.push(false); }
            }
      
      if (result.schoolclass.length) {
         if (result.schoolclass.includes(true)) {
           matches.push(true);
         } else { 
           matches.push(false); 
         }
       }

      var count = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
        if (matches[i] == true)
          count++;
      }

      if (matches.length && matches.length == count) {
        item.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        item.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });

    renderCount(el.list.querySelectorAll('.selected').length);
  }

  function isFilter() {
    var filter = false;
    /**
     * some returns true as soon as any of the callbacks return true,
     * short-circuiting the execution of the rest. e.g., break;
     */
    Array.from(el.filtersList).some(input => {
      if (input.checked) {
        filter = true;
      }
    });
    return filter;
  }

  function onFilterChange(input) {
    var filtered = false;
    if (input.checked) {
      filtered = true;
    } else {
      filtered = isFilter();
    }

    if (filtered) {
      el.list.classList.add('filtered');
      applyFilter();

    } else {
      el.list.classList.remove('filtered');
      renderCount(el.items.length);
    }
  }

  function onDocumentReady() {
    el.heading = document.querySelector('.links-heading');
    el.filters = document.querySelector('.links-filter');
    el.filtersList = el.filters.querySelectorAll('input');
    el.list = document.querySelector('div.links');
    el.items = el.list.querySelectorAll('div.card');

    renderCount(el.items.length);

    Array.from(el.filtersList).forEach(input => {
      // add match count to the label
      input.parentNode.append(` (${matches(input.name, input.value)})`);

      input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        onFilterChange(event.target);
      });
    });

  }

  if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
    onDocumentReady();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDocumentReady);
  }

}());
```

```css
.links.filtered .card:not(.selected) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="links-filter">
Filter 1
<label><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Math"> Math</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Physics"> Physics</label>  <br/>
Filter 2
<label><input type="checkbox" name="form" value="Distance"> Distance</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="form" value="External"> External</label><br/>
Filter 3
<label><input type="checkbox" name="schoolclass" value="Juniorschool"> Juniorschool</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="schoolclass" value="Middleschool"> Middleschool</label>
<h4 class="links-heading"></h4>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <div class="card" data-subject="Math" data-form="Distance" data-schoolclass="Juniorschool">
    <p>Schoolbook for Math</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-subject="Math Physics"  data-form="External">
    <p>Schoolbook for Math and Physics</p>
  </div>
<div class="card" data-subject="English"  data-form="External" data-schoolclass="Middleschool">
    <p>Schoolbook for English</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to provide a minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a value to your results arrays when there is more than one value (separated by commas) in the value of the html element? Please do simplify your code example.

Comment: You can turn a string like `"Geography, English"` into an array `["Geography", "English"]` by calling `.split(/\s?,\s?/)` on it. Next, use array functions like `Array.includes(Element)` to solve this. If you want our help, you need to create a [mre].

Comment: I've gone ahead and made your code a Stack Snippet. You can edit the code by [edit]ing your question and clicking the "edit the above snippet" link below the snippet. Please do edit it, as it is currently incomplete and throws syntax errors.

Comment: It's still not clear to me (after your edit) what you mean by "how to **get** multiple values". Do you mean when the function `matches(key, value)` is called and the `value` parameter is something like _"Math, Geography, English"_ ?

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry , I'm a newbie to JavaScript, I don't have enough knowledge to explain clearly. But you really understood me correctly. I changed my post and code. My code snippet already demonstrates my problem. Unfortunately, I can't solve the problem on my own, so I will be very grateful if you help me, what exactly should I add to the code to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. I have done few tweaks in matches() method and the match() method to include element with data attribute 'Math and Physics' to be shown if we click on either Math or physics

```js
(function() {

  var el = {};

  function matches(key, value) {
    var count = 0;
    Array.from(el.items).forEach(item => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'category':
          if (item.dataset.category && item.dataset.subject.includes(value)) {
            count++;
          }
          break;
        case 'subject':
          if (item.dataset.subject && item.dataset.subject.includes(value)) {
            count++;
          }
          break;
        case 'schoolclass':
          if (item.dataset.schoolclass && item.dataset.schoolclass.includes(value)) {
            count++;
          }
          break;
        case 'form':
          if (item.dataset.form && item.dataset.subject.includes(value)) {
            count++;
          }
          break;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }

  function match(item) {
    var match = {
      "category": [],
      "subject": [],
      "schoolclass": [],
      "form": []
    };
    Array.from(el.filtersList).forEach(input => {
      if (input.checked) {
        switch (input.name) {
          case 'category':
            item.dataset.category && match.category.push(item.dataset.category.includes(input.value));
            break;
          case 'subject':
            item.dataset.subject && match.subject.push(item.dataset.subject.includes(input.value));
            break;
          case 'schoolclass':
            item.dataset.schoolclass && match.schoolclass.push(item.dataset.schoolclass.includes(input.value));
            break;
          case 'form':
            item.dataset.form && match.form.push(item.dataset.form.includes(input.value));
            break;
        }
      }
    });
    return match;
  }

  function renderCount(count) {
    el.heading.innerHTML = `finded: ${count} resources`;
  }

  function applyFilter() {
    Array.from(el.items).forEach(item => {
      var result = match(item),
        matches = [];
      item.classList.remove('selected');

      // console.log(result);
      if (result.category.length) {
        if (result.category.includes(true)) {
          matches.push(true);
        } else {
          matches.push(false);
        }
      }

      if (result.subject.length) {
        if (result.subject.includes(true)) {
          matches.push(true);
        } else {
          matches.push(false);
        }
      }

      if (result.form.length) {
        if (result.form.includes(true)) {
          matches.push(true);
        } else {
          matches.push(false);
        }
      }

      if (result.schoolclass.length) {
        if (result.schoolclass.includes(true)) {
          matches.push(true);
        } else {
          matches.push(false);
        }
      }

      var count = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
        if (matches[i] == true)
          count++;
      }

      if (matches.length && matches.length == count) {
        item.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        item.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });

    renderCount(el.list.querySelectorAll('.selected').length);
  }

  function isFilter() {
    var filter = false;
    /**
     * some returns true as soon as any of the callbacks return true,
     * short-circuiting the execution of the rest. e.g., break;
     */
    Array.from(el.filtersList).some(input => {
      if (input.checked) {
        filter = true;
      }
    });
    return filter;
  }

  function onFilterChange(input) {
    var filtered = false;
    if (input.checked) {
      filtered = true;
    } else {
      filtered = isFilter();
    }

    if (filtered) {
      el.list.classList.add('filtered');
      applyFilter();

    } else {
      el.list.classList.remove('filtered');
      renderCount(el.items.length);
    }
  }

  function onDocumentReady() {
    el.heading = document.querySelector('.links-heading');
    el.filters = document.querySelector('.links-filter');
    el.filtersList = el.filters.querySelectorAll('input');
    el.list = document.querySelector('div.links');
    el.items = el.list.querySelectorAll('div.card');

    renderCount(el.items.length);

    Array.from(el.filtersList).forEach(input => {
      // add match count to the label
      input.parentNode.append(` (${matches(input.name, input.value)})`);

      input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        onFilterChange(event.target);
      });
    });

  }

  if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
    onDocumentReady();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDocumentReady);
  }

}());
```

```css
.links.filtered .card:not(.selected) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="links-filter">
  Filter 1
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Math"> Math</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Physics"> Physics</label> <br />
  Filter 2
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="form" value="Distance"> Distance</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="form" value="External"> External</label><br />
  Filter 3
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="schoolclass" value="Juniorschool"> Juniorschool</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="schoolclass" value="Middleschool"> Middleschool</label>
  <h4 class="links-heading"></h4>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <div class="card" data-subject="Math" data-form="Distance" data-schoolclass="Juniorschool">
    <p>Schoolbook for Math</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-subject="Math Physics" data-form="External">
    <p>Schoolbook for Math and Physics</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-subject="English" data-form="External" data-schoolclass="Middleschool">
    <p>Schoolbook for English</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you helped me a lot! But now I have another problem. I tried to explain it by updating my code snippet. I will be very grateful if you help me again!

Comment: @Liu please accept the answer if that helps you in any way. That is the least we should do if someone puts any effort to solve your question. Anyways I have updated my code above. Few custom data attribute(eg: data-schoolclass) is not available for all the divs, we need to handle those by checking if the element has that specific attribute by using && operator. '&&' executes the second statement(after '&&') only if first statement execution returns true. hope this helps